# Remove infrequent words from ts_vector in postgres full text search

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to make postgres to_tsvector  consider only words which occur more than N times in the table?

The only option I am seeing is to calculate the word frequencies myself beforehand and then construct a dictionary out of that list which replaces each with empty string. Is there any more elegant solution in the configurations ?

Comment: Give some examples to make this question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no dynamic solution. You have to write a stopword file.